# 2012 R2 Domain Controller migrate to 2022 STD

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain, migration, windows-server-2022

I know there are already topics of this nature on the board.  I have a quick question on the 2012 R2 DC.

My setup contains three 2012 R2 Domain Controllers.  One Primary, and two backup DCs.

I want to migrate to 2022 DC.  Do I need to first demote the two backup DC's and delete them entirely, leaving just the primary before migrating to 2022?

Or, can I simply migrate the primary to 2022 and then remove the other two later?

Thanks

---

Thanks for all the advice.  I note now that I am getting Error 5014 on the DFRS replication. Is this something to be concerned about or can i proceed with the 2022 implementation?

The DFS Replication service is stopping communication with partner for replication group Domain System Volume due to an error. The service will retry the connection periodically.

Additional Information:
Error: 9036 (Paused for backup or restore)
Connection ID: C05B985F-BD03-45A1-AC55-DD7CDC888D5F
Replication Group ID: E63EA78B-8407-41F5-B838-640BEE005837

Answer (score 1):

Install the 2022 server alongside and promote it to DC, then demote and decommission the rest. Remember to clean up the AD and to raise the functionality level.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago i also answered a question which was similar to this.

1. I would add the 2022 domain controller as a secondary domain
   controller to the domain, if that's possible with your forest and
   domain level.
2. Then let it sync and replicate for let's say a week. And do some diagnostic tests with dcdiag and so on.
3. Then demote the 2012DC from the domain, and check again. Make sure also all replication links are removed and so on
4. Finish and document

Answer (score 1):

As I just completed this migration myself, I know these steps work.  Some of the other answers are missing some steps.  You also need to consider migration of DNS and DHCP scopes as it is fairly common to include those roles on a domain controller.  It is good you have deployed DFSR as that is a pre-requisite.  If you were still using the older replication system, you would have to migrate before promoting your first 2022 DC.

1. Build out new 2022 Domain Controller (or multiple), join to the domain, and promote to domain controller.  As long as your domain forest and functional level is 2012R2, you can join and promote a 2022 DC.
2. Migrate the FSMO roles to your new domain controllers.  Also migrate the time server settings to the new PDCE that you choose.  Domain joined computers will get their time from a DC, the other DCs in a domain get their time from the PDCE by default.  Check your setup for time settings, this will bite you if you do not change it.
3. Monitor services, move DNS/DHCP (if applicable).  Move other services (hardcoded LDAP authentication, etc.).
4. When ready, demote 2012R2 DCs one at a time.  Clean out connections in AD Sites and Services when the older DC is off.

As for the error you received, if you are performing backups using a snapshot based backup solution or you are using something like Microsoft Data Protection Manager, it will pause DFSR while it performs the backup.  Check replication health with dcdiag and repadmin commands.  Those two tools are better at showing issues that need to be resolved than event viewer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail.  I think I am good to go on the migration.  DFRS also good after running the two commands you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade your domain to a higher version of Active Directory you can upgrade each domain controller in-place or you can add new DCs and then demote the old ones. The term "in-place upgrade" is used to change an existing server to be on a newer version with most of the setting remaining the same. I think that this is what you mean when you write "migrate".

Although this is supported, and I have used this route successfully myself, please note that Microsoft say:

*The recommended way to upgrade a domain is to promote new servers to DCs that run a newer version of Windows Server and demote the older DCs as needed. This method is preferable to upgrading the operating system of an existing DC, which is also known as an in-place upgrade.* (from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/deploy/upgrade-domain-controllers)).

There is no real meaning to "Primary" or "Backup" DCs under Windows Server 2012 R2. There are FSMO roles and if you remove a DC you must transfer any FSMO roles it is holding to another DC first. There are multiple articles showing how to do this.

So to upgrade in place you would **take a good backup of your AD** and upgrade in place any of your DCs in any order.

If you would rather take Microsoft's advice and add new servers on the new OS and then promote them to be a DC then this path is quite simple, although you should consider what IPs the servers end up on because you may well have other devices using the old DCs for DNS resolution and life will be simpler if those lookups still work when you have finished.

At each stage you can check AD synchronisation using DCDIAG. Once synchronisation is complete you can proceed with the next step.

The domain and forest functional levels are important. If the domain and forest functional levels are both set to 2008 or higher then you can install DCs on versions of Windows up to and including Windows Server 2022. If you are on a lower level then you will need to upgrade the domain and/or forest functional level before proceeding. If you are on 2008 or higher and you are thinking of upgrading the level then I would do this after you have upgraded or removed all  older DCs.

It sounds like you may have only one Active Directory site, but consider site links if you have more than one site.